# How to align my component vertically using Material UI in react js?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, material-ui

I am trying to align my Timeline Content vertically so that they are all in one column. Currently, their position is all dependant on the width of the timeline button. I tried Grid, but it would de-align my timeline.

This is the code i have. I have a component for each TimelineItem(TimeStamp) and i added 3 of them in my timeline(History)

```
type TimeProps = {
  name: string;
  last?: boolean;
  date: string;
}
const History = () => {

  const TimeStamp = (props: TimeProps) => {

    const buttonHight = 35;

    const useStyles = makeStyles((theme: Theme) => ({
      paper: {
        display: 'flex',
        height: "100%",
        width: "50%",
        alignItems: "center",
        textAlign: 'center',
        marginTop: -5
      },
      button: {
        borderRadius: 50,
        textTransform: 'none',
        height: buttonHight,
        backgroundColor: '#e0e0e0',
        marginBottom: 3,
        boxShadow: '3',
        justifyContent: 'flex-start',
        maxWidth: 160
      },
      circle: {
        position: 'absolute',
        left: 0,
        height: buttonHight,
        width: buttonHight,
        backgroundColor: '#0d47a1',
        borderRadius: '50%',
        backgroundSize: 'cover',
        display: 'flex',
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center'
      },
      buttonText: {
        color: 'black',
        marginLeft: buttonHight - 10,
        overflow: 'hidden',
        whiteSpace: 'nowrap',
        fontSize: 14
      },
      timelinecontent: {

      },
      buttonBottomText: {
        alignItems: "center",
        textAlign: 'center',
        fontSize: 14,
        fontWeight: 'bold'
      },
      circleText: {
        fontSize: 12
      }
    }));

    const classes = useStyles();

    return (
      <>
        <TimelineItem style={{ height: '20vh' }}>
          <TimelineSeparator>
            <Button className={classes.button} variant='contained' sx={{ boxShadow: 5 }}>
              <div className={classes.circle}>
                <Typography className={classes.circleText}>
                  J
                </Typography>
              </div>
              <Typography className={classes.buttonText}>
                {props.name}
              </Typography>
            </Button>
            <Typography className={classes.buttonBottomText}>
              {props.date}
            </Typography>
            {!props.last && <TimelineConnector />}
          </TimelineSeparator>
          <TimelineContent className={classes.timelinecontent}>
            <Paper elevation={8} className={classes.paper}>
              <div className="content">
                <Typography variant="h2">
                  Content
                </Typography>
              </div>
            </Paper>
          </TimelineContent>
        </TimelineItem>
      </>
    )
  }

  return (
    <Timeline style={{ display: 'flex' }}>
      <TimeStamp
        name="Looong Text"
        date="15-Apr-2020 15:32"
      />
      <TimeStamp
        name="short"
        date="15-Apr-2020 15:32"
      />
      <TimeStamp
        name="Medium"
        date="15-Apr-2020 15:32"
      />
    </Timeline>
  );
}
```

[this is what is shown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YGM0F.png)

Comment: provide the sandbox link of that code that i could figure out .

Comment: alright give me some time to figure out how to do that

Comment: there is the link : https://codesandbox.io/s/async-fog-shil5?file=/src/App.js

Comment: so u want to make all the content box in the line of timeline means in one column ?

Comment: have tried this one , 
https://mui.com/components/timeline/#customization

Comment: it doesnt help because the icons are always the same size contrary to my timeline where i'm using different sized buttons